# Fetching Eventbrite event detail on Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

Below is my VF page and controller, I am trying to fetch event from custom search field value in my VF page. but i am doing something wrong in GET method of eventbrite. Please help . Thanks

VF page

```
<apex:page controller="ESFormController">>
  <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock title="Event Search Form">
       <apex:pageBlockButtons >
               <apex:commandButton value="Search" id="submitButton" reRender="search_event" />
```

Comment: What issue are you facing? Additionally you can directly make api calls from your methods when called from VF pages. No future method is required.

Comment: What i want to do is, there is one search field on my VF page, so when user search event name in that field, it should search from eventbrite(under my organization profile) and list event name on my VF page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Future call will not happen instantly, so you would not return any data... you need to just leave it as a static method.

You will first need to ensure that you have added the Event Bright URL to the your "Remote Site Settings" and update your code a tiny bit:

```
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/?location.address=' + searchstring);
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ***************');

HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
```

Then you can use `res.getBody();` to get the info that is being returned..

Also as a word of warning, you should probably not put your actual auth token as others can use it...

Comment: But as i said before i am getting an error like searchstring variable is not declare. You can see in my code that i have already declare that in class.

Comment: What are you putting in your search criteria?

Comment: You mean what i am trying to search in search field?

Comment: Correct, it looks like it could be an issue with your search criteria not the code

Comment: But because of this error i cant save this apex class. so i havent try to search anything in that field.

Comment: You need to make searchstring static: `public static String searchstring { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a get request, shouldn't you be passing in your search string as a parameter on the endpoint? e.g.

```
String endpoint = 'https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search?location.address=' + searchstring;
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer  ************');
```

NB. I got this from [here](https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/endpoints/events/#ebapi-get-events-search), not sure if that is the correct documentation.

Comment: Tried that but in this i am getting error like Compile Error: Variable does not exist:

Comment: Sounds like you have a syntax error then